# Unable to Create New MVC Widget in Kentico 12

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc

I'm trying to create a new widget called "Image Summary Section". I'm at the very beginning stages and I'm just trying to get the widget to appear in the list of widgets when adding widgets to the page. Instead, I just get existing widgets that I didn't create:

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio and Browser for Kentico Widget Attempt]

You can see that I've created a class that implements `IWidgetProperties` and that I've called `RegisterWidget` for it. I've also created `_ImageSummarySection.cshtml` (though, I wouldn't expect that to be necessary just for the widget to appear in the widget selection dialog).

The top solution is for the MVC website, and the bottom solution is for the Kentico CMS. Both are running, and the browser shown is the Kentico CMS (I'm trying to add my new widget in this screenshot, but it's not in the list of widgets).

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? **How can I get my widget to appear in the list of widgets?**

Additional information:

- I've looked at various links, but here's one I was looking through: https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/developing-websites/page-builder-development/developing-widgets-in-mvc/defining-widget-properties-in-mvc
- I'm on the latest Kentico version, which I think is 12.0.77.

.

.

.

.

.

.

**EDIT:**

I just watched this video, hoping it would provide insight: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljQO9on5lLM

It was more basic than I anticipated, but I did notice these two frames:

[image: Six Widgets]

Note that it shows six available widgets to select from.

And then there was this frame:

[image: Two Widgets]

It shows only two available widgets.

From that, I infer that sections may have some feature that allows developers to constrain which widgets are allowed in them. **Is there perhaps something I need to do in order to allow my widgets to appear as options in the default section (the one shown below)?**

[image: Default Section]

.

.

.

.

.

.

**EDIT #2:**

I researched widget constraints a bit and found this: https://docs.kentico.com/k12/developing-websites/page-builder-development/creating-pages-with-editable-areas-in-mvc

Specifically the section titled "Limiting widgets allowed in an editable area", which says the following:

[image: Limiting Widgets]

Since my view is not passing a parameter with a whitelist of widgets, all widgets should (in theory) be allowed:

```
@* Index.cshtml *@
@using Kentico.PageBuilder.Web.Mvc
@using Kentico.Web.Mvc

<h1>Rhythm Agency</h1>

@Html.Kentico().EditableArea("main")
```

So there goes that theory. I'm still at a loss as to why my new widget isn't appearing as an option when adding new widgets to the page.

Comment: This question is not getting a great response, so I created a new and improved question that shows the latest and greatest changes I've made and new information that I have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959744/how-to-create-an-mvc-widget-in-kentico-12-page-builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the controller and widget to be recognized you need to put your controller in the '/Controllers' folder. I have my widget controllers located in the '/Controllers/Widgets' folder.

I had issues which included not having added the suffix 'Controller' in the class name and issues with the widget controller not being in the '/Controllers' folder.

Also you aren't working in an seperate project? Because this would need you to use the following in the 'AssemblyInfo.cs'

```
using CMS;
[assembly: AssemblyDiscoverable]
```

And make sure you have enabled the page builder feature in your kentico project. For example:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...

    // Gets the ApplicationBuilder instance
    // Allows you to enable and configure Kentico MVC features
    ApplicationBuilder builder = ApplicationBuilder.Current;

    // Enables the preview feature
    builder.UsePreview();

    // Enables the page builder feature
    builder.UsePageBuilder();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For those curious, my issue was that I was missing AssemblyDiscoverable.

It doesn't really matter which folder/namespace the controller is in (though, I have seen issues with some systems in which the "Controller" suffix in the class name is necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  You need to create another class and register your widgets in the App_Start folder. Check out the [documentation here](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/developing-websites/page-builder-development/developing-widgets-in-mvc/example-developing-a-widget-in-mvc) on that.  It's the section on widget registration.  Be sure to [enable Page builder](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/developing-websites/page-builder-development) as well.

*** Updated ***

Based on your update and not being able to see the image well on my mobile device, I was able to see you're defining/registering your widget in your Properties model.  This needs to be done in the Controller.  See the example below.

**\Models\Widgets\JobListingWidgetProperties.cs**

```
namespace NameSpace.Models.Widgets.JobListingWidget
{
    public class JobListingWidgetProperties : IWidgetProperties
    {
        // property definitions here
    }
}
```

**\Models\Widgets\JobListingModelView.cs**

```
namespace NameSpace.Models.Widgets.JobListingWidget
{
    public class JobListingWidgetViewModel
    {
        // properties here
    }
}
```

**\Controllers\Widgets\JobListingWidgetController.cs**

[assembly: RegisterWidget("NameSpace.Widgets.JobListingWidget", typeof(JobListingWidgetController), "Job Listing Widget", Description = "Displays a listing of jobs for a given path", IconClass = "icon-heartshake")]

```
namespace NameSpace.Controllers.Widgets
{
    public class JobListingWidgetController : WidgetController<JobListingWidgetProperties>
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither suggestion is helpful, I'm afraid. I circled a portion of the screenshot showing that I registered the widget (it doesn't need to be in the `App_Start` folder, as that is just a convention (note this is a web application project, not a website project). Also, the screenshot shows I'm using page builder, so it must be enabled already.

Comment: See the updated answer, looks like you're defining/registering the widget in the property class and not the controller like it should be.

Comment: The controller is optional, according to the training and documentation and Dancing Goat samples. However, I created a controller and renamed the widget for good measure (in case "Section" is a reserved word), and that didn't help.

Comment: I created a new question to show my updates so we can start fresh: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959744/how-to-create-an-mvc-widget-in-kentico-12-page-builder

Comment: Ok you got me there, yes the controller is optional.  BUT if you don't have a controller, then you need to initialize that widget as I mentioned in my initial response using a separate class.  While placing it in the properties class should work, I'd follow what Kentico is recommending.  It works every time for us without issue.  https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/developing-websites/page-builder-development/developing-widgets-in-mvc/example-developing-a-widget-in-mvc

Comment: As I stated on the other question, adding the controller did not help. Also, adding the assembly attribute in another file is a stylistic choice, not one that would prevent it from working.

Give it a shot on one of your projects; see if adding the assembly attribute in the properties class prevents it from working. I bet you it would work fine (assuming your widget is already working).

Comment: FYI, I moved the widget registration assembly attribute to a class in the `App_Start` folder, and that didn't help, as expected.

Comment: I'm assuming you're rebuilding your solution after you make the changes. Just have to check.