# Inherited Kentico MVC Widget not registering in the CMS Admin site

Tags: kentico

I am registering a custom kentico widget.
When it was created, I could not locate it in the collection of other widgets on the page tab in the admin website of the CMS solution.

I also looked for my widget in the CMS_Widget Table with no luck. Is there another table which might house custom widgets?

My Controller

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Website.Contracts;
using Company.Views.FeaturedProduct;

[assembly: RegisterWidget(OptInOptOutWidgetController.Identifier, typeof(OptInOptOutWidgetController), "Opt In Opt Out List", Description = "Lists all products that are opted in", IconClass = "icon-bullseye")]
namespace Website.Controllers.Widgets
{
    public class OptInOptOutWidgetController : WidgetController
    {
        public const string Identifier = "Website.Controllers.Widgets.OptInOptOutWidgetController";
        public IApplyLoanService ApplyLoanService { get; }


        public OptInOptOutWidgetController( IApplyLoanService _ApplyLoanService)
    {
        ApplyLoanService = _ApplyLoanService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<StateInfo> stateInfoList = ApplyLoanService.GetStateDetails();
            List<SelectListItem> statesList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            OptInOptOutWidgetViewModel viewModel = new OptInOptOutWidgetViewModel();

            viewModel.StateList = stateInfoList.Where(x => x.StateName != null).Select(x => new OptInOptOutStateViewModel
            {
                StateName = x.StateName
            }).ToList();

            ViewBag.States = viewModel.StateList;

            return PartialView("Widgets/OptInOptOut/_OptInOptOutProductList", viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

My View

```
@using Company.Models.Widgets
@model  Company.Models.Widgets.OptInOptOut.OptInOptOutWidgetViewModel


@if (Context.Kentico().PageBuilder().EditMode && Context.Kentico().PageBuilder().Initialized())
{
    @Html.Kentico().PageBuilderScripts()
}

<div>
    @if (Model.StateList != null)
    {
        <p>Select State</p>

        <select>
            @Html.DropDownList("States", new SelectList(Model.StateList), "")
        </select>
    }
    else
    {
        <p>There are no states</p>
    }
</div>
```

I referenced this post:
[Unable to Create New MVC Widget in Kentico 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62947063/unable-to-create-new-mvc-widget-in-kentico-12)

I started making updates the code base but still nothing:

- The AssemblyDiscoverable was already where it was supposed to be

We have other widgets published to the CMS but there is no clear path on how to reproduce. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The `CMS_Widget` table is used for Portal Engine Widgets, which are very different from MVC Page Builder Widgets.

Portal Engine Widgets are used to create the Administration UI which is still built on ASP.NET Web Forms technology.

MVC Page Builder Widgets are not used anywhere in the Administration UI, only on the Live Site.

There is no database table that records all Widgets (or any Page Builder components) defined in the Live Site. Instead, these are all discovered at runtime by the Xperience framework based on your `[assembly: RegisterX(...)]` [component registration attributes](https://docs.xperience.io/developing-websites/page-builder-development/developing-widgets#Developingwidgets-Registeringwidgets).

Your Widget will appear in the Page Builder UI in a dialog that opens when you click the + [button in a Widget Zone](https://docs.xperience.io/managing-website-content/adding-page-content-using-widgets).

If your Widget is registered in the MVC Live Site application, you do not need the `AssemblyDiscoverable` attribute - that is only required when your Xperience components are in separate class libraries. `AssemblyDiscoverable` tells Xperience to scan the class library assembly for components - without it, scanning that assembly is skipped.

Comment: I would like to add that it is also possible that the editable area has limited widgets allowed and the new widget is not listed: https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/developing-websites/page-builder-development/creating-pages-with-editable-areas-in-mvc#CreatingpageswitheditableareasinMVC-Limitingwidgetsallowedinaneditablearea